# TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/ Error

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-registration

So I am new to Django and am currently trying to build registration into my app. I have already followed this [guide](http://code.techandstartup.com/django/registration/#app-download). However I am running into an issue in which the application is not able to find the template somehow.

> ```
> Traceback:
> ```
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     215.                 response = response.render()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in render
>     109.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     84.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in resolve_template
>     66.             return select_template(template, using=self.using)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in
>   select_template
>     53.         raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
>
> Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/ Exception
>   Value: registration/registration_form.html

I have checked to make sure my URL are set and everything should be in order. I have spent the past 2 hours looking for a solution to this and nothing is working.

The things that gets me the most is that in the error I can see where it checks for the template in the exact place I have it yet I am still seeing the following next to the actual path in which this template should be.

> (Source does not exist)

Please help

Comment: Do you in fact have a template named `registration/registration_form.html`?  Is that file readable by the web server wsgi process?  How have you specified your template directories in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, the template is in fact there and it is readable. I think the issue is with my template directories but being the newbie that I am I do not know what I am doing wrong. Here is my `settings.py` code below.

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/accounts/register/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/templates/'),
]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that you have defined TEMPLATES_DIRS properly

In Django 1.8 upwards:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here (absolute path)
        ],
    },
]
```

Comment: Make sure the path is absolute

Comment: I am using django-registration, does this still apply when using a package such as that?

Comment: Yes, for each path you intend to put templates to

Answer (score 2):

For Django 1.11.x your TEMPLATES should look like this:

```
`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\','/'),),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'loaders': (
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ),
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG
        },
    },
] `
```